# how to include fabric.js file in script

Tags: jquery, html, css, fabricjs

i want to try basic fabric  plugin  file ,when i copy code and run nothing is displayed on screen.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <script></script>
    <script src="js/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
  <script src="js/fabric.js"></script>
  <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
   var circle = new fabric.Circle({
  radius: 20, fill: 'green', left: 100, top: 100
});
var triangle = new fabric.Triangle({
  width: 20, height: 30, fill: 'blue', left: 50, top: 50
});

canvas.add(circle, triangle);
});
</script>

</head>

<body>
  <div>
    <header>
      <h1>canvas</h1>
    </header>





</body>
</html>
```

this is the code i have copied , but it is displayoing nothing .

**EDIT::**

i solved this . i was making mistaking i wans not creating  element inside body tag .

Comment: Did you put correct path for .js file inside <script> tag

Answer (score 4):

adding canvs element in body solved the problem :)....

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <script></script>
    <script src="js/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
  <script src="js/fabric.js"></script>
  <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('canvas');

var rect = new fabric.Rect({
  top: 100,
  left: 100,
  width: 60,
  height: 70,
  fill: 'red'
});
canvas.add(rect);
});
</script>

</head>

<body>
  <div>
    <header>
      <h1>canvas</h1>
    </header>
   <canvas id="canvas" width="300" height="300"></canvas>




</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes Simmi is right, you need add Canvas element in page.

```
    <canvas id="canvas" width="300" height="300"></canvas>
```

here is the live example. http://jsfiddle.net/swapnilvathare/hxjZa/

Answer (score 0):

wrap the script code in document ready function

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 //your code goes here
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <script src="js/jquery-1.9.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="js/fabric.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function(){
     var circle = new fabric.Circle({
     radius: 20, fill: 'green', left: 100, top: 100
     });
     var triangle = new fabric.Triangle({
     width: 20, height: 30, fill: 'blue', left: 50, top: 50
     });
     canvas.add(circle, triangle);
      });
      </script>

    </head>
    <body>
      <div>
        <header>
          <h1>canvas</h1>
        </header>
    </body>
    </html>
```